# iOS provisioning portal - have to be a paid dev?

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I am a new iphone dev.
The book i am reading does not mention this but do I have to be a paid dev to access provisioning portal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be an iPhone Developer which costs $99 a year. You don't need access to be a developer mind, you just can't publish to a device or to the app store without it.

When you log in to the Apple Developer website you have access to tonnes of resources to help you. $99 a year is a good price I think, given what you have access to. You need access to the provisioning portal allows you to publish to an iPhone/iPad and on to the app store. But if you don't want to pay, you can still have access to the SDK